# If you pass args from a variadic function to another function with va_list, how do you call va_start (without error)

Tags: c++

I've seen answers here to questions on how to pass variadic args from one function to another that say use a va_list to pass to the 2nd function.  Great, when I tried this, va_start doesn't like the passed in va_list passed in...

```
void foo(const char *str, va_list args) {
  va_start(args, str);
  //do something
  va_end(args);
}

void foo(const char *str, ...) {
  va_list args;
  foo(str, args);
}
```

I get this error from g++:

`error: ‘va_start’ used in function with fixed args`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code causes undefined behaviour as you have used `args` uninitialized in `foo`. The correct way is:

```
void foo(const char *str, va_list args) {
  //do something
}

void foo(const char *str, ...) {
  va_list args;
  va_start(args, str);
  foo(str, args);
  va_end(args);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to call `va_start` in your variadic function. Same for `va_end`:

```
void foo (const char * str, va_list args )
{
    /* ... */
}

void foo (const char * str, ... )
{
    va_list args;

    va_start( args, str );
    foo( str, args );
    va_end( args );
}
```